# Изменение значения свойства, указанного в анимации

Tags: javascript, jquery, css3, анимация

Есть CSS3 анимация. Захотелось значение свойства `right` брать из переменной. Анимация просто перестала работать.

```js
function load_style() {
    var window_width = $("html").width();
    var window_height = $("html").height();
    var text_page_1_width = $(".text#page_1").width();
    $('.info_panel').css('width', (window_width - text_page_1_width) / 2 + 'px');
    $('.info_panel').css('right', '-' + (window_width - text_page_1_width) / 2 + 'px');
}
$(function() {
    $(document).ready(function() {
          load_style();
    });
    var $info_panel = $('.info_panel');
    $('.el1').on("click", function() {
        $info_panel.toggleClass('slide_panel');
    });
});
```

```css
.slide_panel {
right: 0;
}
.info_panel {
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #565656;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 100;
  top: 0;
  margin: auto;
  -webkit-transition: right .325s linear;
  -moz-transition: right .325s linear;
  -ms-transition: right .325s linear;
  -o-transition: right .325s linear;
  transition: right .325s linear;
}
.el1 {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  left: 1.5vw;
  top: 2.75vh;
  width: 5.75vw;
  color: #565656;
  border: .4vw solid #565656;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="info_panel">// Панель
  <span class="i">i</span>
</div>
<div class="el1">// Кнопка, которая запускает анимацию панели
  <span id="show_info_panel">i</span>
</div>
```

Анимации нет. Если задать начальное значение `right`, то анимации тоже нет. В чем ошибка и как можно добавить это свойство (`right`), чтобы анимация работала?

Comment: А я не вижу. Если всё бы работало корректно, то панель сдвигалась бы на (window_width - text_page_1_width) / 2. Если панель не сдвигается, значит в коде что-то не так. Что же не так? Плюс, с width всё работает, а с right нет.

Comment: Вот это изменение вопроса весьма важно. Стоило изначально указывать код именно так.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема в том, что заданное у конкретного элемента `.info_panel` (в функции `load_style`) CSS свойство `right` является более приоритетным, чем заданное у `.slide_panel`.
Поэтому значение `right` у элемента не меняется при добавлении/удалении класса.

Вариант решения: менять `right` при каждом клике.

- `Math.floor()` добавлен к `right`, чтобы избежать проблем с дробными числами.
- Нужное значение `right` хранится в `$info_panel.data('right')`
- При клике сравнивается текущее значение `right` с сохранённым в `$info_panel.data('right')`. В зависимости от этого выбирается и устанавливается новое значение `right`.

```js
function load_style() {
    var window_width = $("html").width();
    var window_height = $("html").height();
    var text_page_1_width = $(".text#page_1").width();
    var $info_panel = $('.info_panel');
    $info_panel.css('width', (window_width - text_page_1_width) / 2 + 'px');
    var right = - Math.floor((window_width - text_page_1_width) / 2);
    $info_panel.data('right', right);
    $info_panel.css('right', right + 'px');
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    load_style();
    var $info_panel = $('.info_panel');
    $('.el1').on("click", function() {
        var curRight = parseInt($info_panel.css('right'));
        var newRight = 0;
        if (curRight != $info_panel.data('right')) {
            newRight = $info_panel.data('right');
        }
        console.log('newRight: ' + newRight);
        $info_panel.css('right', newRight + "px");
    });
});
```

```css
.info_panel {
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #565656;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 100;
  top: 0;
  margin: auto;
  -webkit-transition: right .325s linear;
  -moz-transition: right .325s linear;
  -ms-transition: right .325s linear;
  -o-transition: right .325s linear;
  transition: right .325s linear;
}
.el1 {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  left: 1.5vw;
  top: 2.75vh;
  width: 5.75vw;
  color: #565656;
  border: .4vw solid #565656;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="info_panel">// Панель
  <span class="i">i</span>
</div>
<div class="el1">// Кнопка, которая запускает анимацию панели
  <span id="show_info_panel">i</span>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Пример в [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jyq2d6oe/).

Comment: Спасибо. Как-то об этом даже не подумал

Comment: @АлёшкаЛаврушка на здоровье. Это проще всего увидеть при инспекции элементов в браузере.

Answer (score 0):

Собственно, где у Вас анимация? Ее нет, поэтому она и не работает.

Если нужно анимировать движение `.info_panel`, то укажите в CSS начальное значение свойства `right`.

Comment: Она есть. Сейчас дополню код. И как я уже писал, пробовал задавать начальное значение. Так анимация перестаёт тоже работать.

Comment: Как-то так. Не уверен что всё работает тут корректно. Но в коде я передал суть. У меня анимация в виде обычного toogle.